# Post Migrate Development to Live Production Server issue

Tags: migrations, installation

I'm positive I've successfully done this before but in testing a project today from a localhost Development (Ubuntu) to a live Production server (shared server, general market provider ala Bluehost) I'm getting a White Screen Of Death (WSOD) after importing the main filename.sql via phpmyadmin and I'm not sure why it's not working correctly.

Here's what I'm doing:

1) - copy via FTP all core and /sites/modules and my relevant dir contents.

2) - setup all Database with user/passwords including Admin as required.

3) - install generic Drupal v.7.2x onto server using Drupal /install.php

this then gets me a 'Standard' install but without all my data content but all accessable as per a generic standard Drupal install.

Next, back to phpmyAdmin, go to the relevant DB structure and chose 'Import', because I'm using a raw. sql I can just select the 22.5mg .sql file and wait, then I get the 'Success' message. I cannot use Backup & Migrate (M&G) Module due to the file limitation given my B&M.

After this point, I get a WSOD and cannot move forward.

The only thing I know that is different is that on my locahost Dev I used a simple 'Admin' name and a simple Password such as 'DeadEasy'. On the live Prod site, I changed this for better security to a name relevant to a SuperUser (ie AlphaBravoCharlie,(thats NOT real!!), Password: such as "DrG6%7DyE".

FYI, I did have some Fatal Errors yesterday based on Memory allocation, (I'm allowed 128meg max) but the example highlighted here is after I reduced module load to resolve the previous fatal error given.

Can anyone shed any light on what may have happened?

Notes #1: 
I had thought it may have been that I hadn't uploaded my 'sites/all/themes', but it wasn't. #2 any other 'test' index.html work fine (as in temporarily disabling the index.php).

Comment: You need to check the logs really. Probably a missing module or an error in sites/default/settings.php. The log file will tell you why you are WSOD. Do you have SSH to bluehost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first place to look would be the BlueHost Error Logs; their article at https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/562 describes where to find them within cPanel. If you're seeing failed calls to functions / modules that you know exist in your codebase, there's a strong probability that Drupal's registry is not current.

Drupal caches extension (module and theme) file locations within its registry. Given that you are importing an existing site database into a different structure, those locations are out-of-date.

If you haven't already, I suggest installing Drush (the DRUpal SHell) using the instructions at https://drupal.org/node/1181480

Then, clear the site cache:

```
drush cc all
```

If that does not clear it up, the next step is a registry rebuild. This forces Drupal to rescan executable file locations. Install the Drupal contrib project registry_rebuild using the instructions on the project homepage, then

```
drush rr
```

to rebuild the registry.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I'll follow your advice and post result here.

Comment: I managed to resolve this issue. I'd say the issues were from a combination of max memory of 128meg which I resolved by turning off suggested UI items (Views, etc) which helped reduced my .sql file, but still down to 22meg. I couldn't use Backup & Migrate and in the end had to use phpMyAdmin to import to DB. I also think I a 'mismatch' with the settings.php for the user admin account details as they were still set to a 'vanilla' Admin, simple PW combination. I also changed the settings in the Current PHP version v5.5 so that upload memory was to 32meg. Then it all worked fine.

Comment: Fantastic, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

If the MySQL file is too large for the web host's limits in phpMyAdmin, consider using the [BigDump](https://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage/) script. Download & edit the BigDump PHP file, then run from a web browser at:  http://www.yourdomain.com/dump/bigdump.php to upload the MySQL in a staggered manner to get around the time-out limits. This requires the "Drop Table" setting on the original MySQL export file to be used in the database transfer. Also, make sure to use PHP 7.2+ settings for Drupal 8 at Bluehost.